# Spark writing files with custom extension

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame that contains a single row of text. I need to write, while each file (from each DataFrame partition) has custom extension `.XYZ`. Currently ,I am using the following code to write the files:

```
dataFrame.write.text(outputPath)
```

However, this code writes files with the default extension.
Currently, I control the extension by renaming the files after being written, by I would like to optimize this by writing the files with required extension.
How can I achieve writing the file with extension different than default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for same extension for all files.

```
df.write.format("csv/txt/parquest/etc").mode("overwrite").save("outputPath")
```

You can try this for different file extension for each partition.

```
val files = List("abc.csv","bdc.txt")
  df.repartition(2).rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx,itr)=>itr.map(x=>(x,idx))).foreachPartition { itr => {
    if (itr.hasNext) {
      val lst=itr.toList
      val index = lst(0)._2
      val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("abc." + extension(index)))
      val stringToWrite = lst.mkString("\n")

      bw.write(stringToWrite)
      bw.close()
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: The first option does not work for me because I need a custom extension. The second option does the work done, although I had to modify it for my needs. Thanks for you answer